# Merge two tables and keep smaller value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two tables and want to keep the smaller values of `FC` and `FH` for common `Tasks`. Tables look like this:

```
x <- data.frame("Task" = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                "FC" = c(12,NA,15,14,NA),
                "FH" = c(13,15,NA,17,20))
  Task FC FH
1    A 12 13
2    B NA 15
3    C 15 NA
4    D 14 17
5    E NA 20

y <- data.frame("Task" = c("B","C","F","G"),
                "FC" = c(NA,12,20,NA),
                "FH" = c(NA,17,18,NA))
  Task FC FH
1    B NA NA
2    C 12 17
3    F 20 18
4    G NA NA
```

How can I use the function `melt` to get a result like this:

```
  Task FC FH
1    A 12 13
2    B NA 15
3    C 12 17
4    D 14 17
5    E NA 20
6    F 20 18
7    G NA NA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `data.table` solution would be

```
# Bring together the two tables
z <- funion(as.data.table(x),as.data.table(y))

# Find the min of FC and FH for each Task
z <- z[, .(FC = min(FC, na.rm = T), FH = min(FH, na.rm = T)), by = "Task"]

# Replace Infs returned by min with NA
z[is.infinite(FC), FC := NA]
z[is.infinite(FH), FH := NA]
```

Answer (score 4):

One option is to full join and keep minimum value for each `Task`

```
aggregate(.~Task, merge(x, y, all = TRUE), min, na.rm = TRUE,na.action = "na.pass")

#  Task  FC  FH
#1    A  12  13
#2    B Inf  15
#3    C  12  17
#4    D  14  17
#5    E Inf  20
#6    F  20  18
#7    G Inf Inf
```

This returns `Inf` instead of `NA` though which can be changed to `NA` if needed.

```
out[out == Inf] <- NA
```

Same in `dplyr`, would be

```
library(dplyr)

full_join(x, y) %>%
   group_by(Task) %>%
   summarise_all(min, na.rm = TRUE)
```